# LEFT and RIGHT JOIN multiple table, show all null data on mariadb 10.3

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

i want to join 3 table with null value,
here i have 3 table folowing

```
tbl_reporting                               tbl_criteria                   tbl_student
|===============================|           |========================|     |===============|
| id | id_criteria | id_student |           | id |   name    |weight |     | id |   name   |
|===============================|           |========================|     |===============|
| 1  |     2       |      3     |           |  1 | worrying  |  3    |     | 1  | Nina     |
| 2  |     1       |      2     |           |  2 | naughty   |  2    |     | 2  | Adam     |
| 3  |     1       |      1     |           |  3 | usually   |  2    |     | 3  | Dodi     |
| 4  |     2       |      2     |           |  4 | good      |  1    |     | 4  | Zarah    |
| 5  |     1       |      1     |           |  5 | obey      |  1    |     | 5  | Udep     |
```

and the result i want, like this

```
result
| id | student_name   | criteria_name | weight |
|==============================================|
| 1  | Dodi           |    naughty    |   2    |
| 2  | Adam           |    worrying   |   3    |
| 3  | Nina           |    worrying   |   3    |
| 4  | Adam           |    naughty    |   2    |
| 5  | Nina           |    worrying   |   3    |
|NULL| Zarah          |      NULL     |   0    |    
|NULL| Udep           |      NULL     |   0    |    
|NULL| NULL           |     usualy    |   0    |    
|NULL| NULL           |      good     |   0    |    
|NULL| NULL           |      obey     |   0    |
```

i try myself.. but not what i expected.
here i code self : [link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c08bbe4dc8853e55386deb20dd9fb754)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT r.id, s.name student_name, c.name criteria_name, c.weight
FROM tbl_reporting r
JOIN tbl_student s ON r.id_student = s.id
JOIN tbl_criteria c ON r.id_criteria = c.id
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, s.name, NULL, 0
FROM tbl_student s
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM tbl_reporting r
                   WHERE r.id_student = s.id )

UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, c.name, 0
FROM tbl_criteria c
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM tbl_reporting r
                   WHERE r.id_criteria = c.id );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=989338bb30f2f5b4d7be4667763e9522

Comment: ohh thanks.. its work